# video tag bar position - html

Tags: html, css, position, html5-video

**See what I'm talking about here(http://jsfiddle.net/VpLyR/).
[image]

I have a completely simple code contains a `video` tag (html) and a fixed position menu bar.
The problem that when I scroll down till the menu bar and the video bar becomes on the same line, the video bar displays on the menu bar and hide it [image], but all what I want that the menu bar displays on the video bar and **hide** it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a simple z index. Check it out?

http://jsfiddle.net/VpLyR/

Hope this helps. If I have misunderstood, let me know.

```
#fixed-menu{
width:100%;
height:50px;
background-color:red;
position:fixed;
z-index: 999;
```

}

video { z-index: -1;}